# Check if array contained within another in rego

Tags: arrays, set, contains, open-policy-agent, rego

I have two arrays: `x` and `y`
I want to check if `x` is contained within `y`.

There is not contains() function in rego.

Next thing I tried is to create the mathematical equivalent to the contains() function:

`x ⊆ y ⇔ (x ⋂ y) == x`.

So I tried to do the following:

```
z := x & y
x == z
```

But this creates the following error:

> rego_type_error: and: invalid argument(s)
> have: (array[any], any, ???)
> want: (set[any], set[any], set[any])

So how can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Set operations](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/policy-reference/#sets-2) only work on.. well, sets :) If you are creating `x` and  `y` as new sets (just use `{...}` instead of `[...]`) your example should work. If `x` and `y` are arrays - like is often the case when referencing values from the `input` - you can use a set comprehension to convert them, like:

```
xs := {e | e := x[_]}
ys := {e | e := y[_]}
```

And then use `xs` and `ys` as sets. If you on the other hand really want to use arrays (like when ordering and duplicate values matter), you could do something like this:

```
contained {
    y[i]
    x == array.slice(y, i, i + count(x))
}
```

This would iterate over the `y` array, and for each item create a slice of `y` from `i` and to the same length as the `x` array, and return true if one such slice is equal to `x`.

Comment: is the set version faster? is set comprehension expensive?

Comment: Yes, the set version would be faster. Set comprehension is not expensive in itself, but it obviously depends on what you do inside of the comprehension :)